# Asset Pipeline: Ignore ceratin file types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typescript, asset-pipeline, source-maps

I've got a Rails 4 project which has `.js.map` files in the `app/assets/sourcemaps` directory, and `.ts` files in the `app/assets/typescripts directory.` However, when running `rake assets:precompile`, the precompile that Sprockets uses will crash with an error akin to:

```
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: punc (:) (line: 1, col: 10, pos: 10)

Error
  ....... a backtrace ......
  (in $APP_ROOT/app/assets/sourcemaps/index_uploads_controller.js.map)
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Of course, the failure makes sense, as a .js.map file is not a javascript file, but still Sprockets tries to do something with it.

How can I make Sprockets ignore these files? I've tried toying around with `Sprockets::Rails::Helper#asset_needs_precompile?`, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. There are also a few questions already on SO which seem to have a similar problem, but the solutions do not work for Rails 4.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no simple way (I know of) to exclude things from the assets precompile until it becomes part of [sprockets by default](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/pull/311).  You have a few options.

1. Write a new precompile include statement that ignores sourcemaps: (example via [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html))

## config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```

1. Use something like [coffee-rails-source-maps](https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps) which will help you get things setup for a dev only environment.
2. Move the sourcemaps out of the `app/assets` directory manually somewhere else and enter a world of pain as you try to map them all while ensuring they aren't committed into the repo or built into the asset pipiline.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to place all you css files in a sub directory of stylesheets, such as assets/stylesheets/application and all your js files in a sub directory of javascripts, such as assets/javascripts/application

Then in you js manifest replace `//= require_tree .` by `//= require_tree ./application` and in your css manifest replace `*= require_tree .` by `*= require_tree ./application`

That would leave your sourcemaps and typescripts directories out of the compilation scope